# Add math symbols in an annotation

Tags: matlab, annotations

How can I added a note on a figure plot in Matlab which contain math symbols (kappa, gamma, alpha, symbol of containing, ...) as explained in the image:

[image]

Comment: Did you look into the [`text`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) command, and the `'interpreter'` options? You can use TeX and LaTeX to display pretty much anything... BTW - this information is [not exactly hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYg2t.png).

Answer (score 1):

You can add a text label using the [**`text`**](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) command.

For example

```
plot(0:10, (0:10).^2);
% Add text at x=5, y=10
text(5, 10, 'this is text');
% Add text at x=5, y=50, with Greek letters
text(5, 50, '\pi is nice, \alpha is too');
```

This works because the interpreter is set to [LaTeX](https://www.latex-project.org/about/) by default. For the full list of supported TeX commands, see [**this list**](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html#inputarg_Interpreter) in the documentation. In particular, since you asked about Greek letters, here is a basic list. Most are as you would expect, preceded by a backslash:

```
Character Sequence  Symbol
\alpha              α
\beta               β
\gamma              γ
\delta              δ
\epsilon            ɛ
\zeta               ζ
\eta                η
\theta              Θ
\kappa              κ
\lambda             λ
\mu                 µ
\xi                 ξ
\pi                 π
\rho                ρ
\sigma              σ
```

---

**Notes on the LaTeX interpreter.**

You can also render maths inside text captions (or axes labels, and chart titles) using $inline mode$ or $$display mode$$. See the linked docs for more details.

You can set the default interpreter to LaTeX (if for some reason it isn't) using

```
set(0,'defaulttextinterpreter','latex')
```

Answer (score 0):

The default interpreter is already latex so all you have to do is something like this as an example. not the `backslash` to access the latex commands. You will have to search what symbols you want on the internet.

```
    legend('\rho = 0.5')
```